# Assetconflict after changing general.php

Tags: matrix

I've made a matrix field on one of my templates. After adding alot of content, and then trying to delete it, I get this message:

> include(/home/blabla/bla/craft/app/enums/AssetConflictResolution.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

The reason might be that I changed my basepath in general.php / staging issues. Any idea, anyone?

Answer (score 3):

If it were related to `basePath`, then you'd most likely be getting other errors as well.

This one sounds like Craft simply can't autoload the file it's looking for.  I'd re-upload your `craft/app` folder to make sure all of the files got transferred up properly and aren't corrupted.